# XML parsing: line 1, character 7, text/xmldecl not at the beginning of input

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I am trying to insert a bit of xml in a xml column in my table, however I am getting an error

> XML parsing: **line 1, character 7, text/xmldecl not at the beginning of input.

It worked fine in 2012 but its balking in 2008 R2, here's the XML I'm trying to insert... I have it down to its smallest size:

```
@xml = N'"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-16\"?>"'
```

No clue why its different in 2008 R2. I have tried many different ways of representing that opening tag, but none have worked.

Including

```
@xml = N'"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>"'
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: Are you sure you're using the XML datatype on both SQL Server 2008 and 2012? I don't see that code running in SQL Server 2012.